# Why am I getting an RTNETLINK Operation Not Permitted when using Pipework with Docker containers?

Tags: docker

I'm running CoreOS stable 494.5.0 using Vagrant/VirtualBox and am running the vanilla ruby:2.1.5 Docker image. I'm trying to use Pipework to connect the Docker container to a local physical interface (as opposed to using `--net=host` when running the container) so I can sniff traffic. Pipework creates `eth1@if2` in the container and sets its IP address correctly, but the link ends up in the `UNKNOWN` state and when I try to bring the link up using `ip link` I get `RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted`.

If it makes a difference, I have to use `ip link set dev eth1 up` instead of `ip link set dev eth1@if2 up` or else I get `Cannot find device "eth1@if2"`.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Docker containers do not have full privileges by default.   Try adding this to the `docker run` command:

```
--cap-add=NET_ADMIN
```

[List of capabilities](http://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities)

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the Operation Not Permitted issue! I still can't sniff traffic from within the container on the local interface I'm using Pipework to link to, but that's for another SO question. ;)

Comment: Note: if you're using `docker-compose`, use `cap_add` key for given container with `NET_ADMIN` as a value (must be an array, i.e. `- NET_ADMIN` on the next line)

Comment: I was getting this error because I was adding this option at the end. All the options should be before the arguments.
```bash
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "--cap-add=NET_ADMIN": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
```

Answer (score 17):

In your `docker-compose.yml` you can add this:

```yaml
container_or_service_name:
  cap_add:
    - NET_ADMIN
```

Credit where credit is due: this answer is based on a [comment by @petrkotek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27708376/why-am-i-getting-an-rtnetlink-operation-not-permitted-when-using-pipework-with-d#comment69947061_27708858) under the accepted answer, but I ended up using it myself, so I wanted to make it more visible.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Portainer, you can activate the option [Advanced Container Settings > Capabilities > NET_ADMIN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDEIL.png).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35172333)