# "RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted" during `docker build`

Tags: docker, network-programming

I want to build a Docker image with latency+loss on some localhost ports using `tc` and `netem`.
The `tc` command works on a regular vm, but not in the Dockerfile.

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" \
    apt-get update --fix-missing && \
    apt-get -y install \
    apt-utils \
    software-properties-common \
    iproute2

RUN tc qdisc add dev lo root handle 1: htb
```

I attempt to build it with this command:

```
docker build .
```

But it fails on the RUN command with this error:

```
Step 3/3 : RUN tc qdisc add dev lo root handle 1: htb
 ---> Running in 59b27236040b
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27708376/2037637), but my problem occurs during `docker build`, not `docker run`. There is no way for me to specify `--cap-add` because that is not an option for `docker build`.

Comment: This operation doesn't really make sense.  Docker doesn't have fully virtualized networking and a container can't usually control its network environment in this level of detail; also an image is only a filesystem plus some metadata describing how to start the container, and runtime settings like this aren't persisted in the image.  I'd stick with a VM here.

Comment: I'm still new to Docker so it would make sense that I've misunderstood its capabilities. But netem is [something people use](https://github.com/alexei-led/pumba#network-emulation-netem-command) in containers at run-time, and I want to apply this configuration to all containers derived from the image, so to me the logical place to specify these settings was the Dockerfile. Sounds like I need to somehow do this at run-time instead, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As one of the comments said, it does not make sense to RUN a `tc` command during the build phase.

The workaround I used was:

1. Add permissions for `tc` in the container (if the eventual container user is not root), but don't actually RUN any of the `tc` commands in the Dockerfile.
2. Build the container as normal.
3. Run the container, adding `--cap-add=NET_ADMIN`
4. From inside the running container, execute the `tc` commands.